# Why can 'self.method' not use a method in the same class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why when I do `self.method` from a class, I get an `` undefined method `my_method' for MyModule::MyOtherModule::MyClass:Class ``

```
module MyModule
 module OtherModule
  class MyClass < Base

   def my_method
   end

   def self.my_self_method
    my_method
   end

  end
 end
end
```

I call `my_self_method` with `send` from an herited [sic] class:

```
class Base
 class << self
  my_method(method_name)
   send("my_self_#{method_name}")
  end
 end
end
```

I don't understand it.

Comment: Because `self` in `my_self_method` is `MyClass` class, not `MyClass` instance.

Comment: Thanks, so is it not possible to call ``my_method`` ?

Comment: It is not possible to call instance method from class method scope. You can create instance inside class method and then call methods on it: `new.my_method`. But if you have to do such things it's a sing that it's a bad code.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're defining one instance method (`my_method`), and one class method (`my_self_method`).

This means you can call:

```
MyClass.my_self_method
```

or

```
MyClass.new.my_method
```

If you want `my_method` to be callable from `my_self_method`, you could define it as:

```
def self.my_method
  ...
end
```

Then the following would be available:

```
def self.my_self_method
  my_method
end
```

Here's another alternative. There's a comment that suggests it's bad practice to call `new.my_method` from within a class method, but I've seen a pattern that applies this that I find quite idiomatic, for example:

```
class MyClass
  def self.run(the_variables)
    new(the_variables).process
  end

  def initialize(the_variables)
    # setup the_variables
  end

  def process
    # do whatever's needed
  end
end
```

This allows a simple entry point of `MyClass.run(the_variables)`. If your use case seems suitable, a similar pattern for you would be:

```
module MyModule
  module OtherModule
    class MyClass < Base

      def my_method
      end

      def self.my_self_method
        new.my_method
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sure there's scope to disagree with this pattern, and would be interested to hear others' opinions in the comments.

Hope this helps clear a few things up @N.Safi.

Comment: Did this help at all @N.Safi?